# proxy configuration file not read

Tags: angular, rest

My development environment angular server runs on localhost:4200 and spring boot server runs on localhost:8080. Angular service invokes rest api calls using

```
this.http.get(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':8080/' +'<context-path>/api/<endpoint>');
```

Proxy configuration file:

```
{
    "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:800/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": false
    }
}
```

I am starting my server using

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Intentionally I provided port number as 800, Still I can get results from server. This made sure for me that proxy configuration file is not being read.

When we can directly access the url from angular service, why do we need proxy configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of proxy file is basically telling angular to check the request's url and replace it with the target if matched.
In your case, try requesting `this.http.get('api/something')`, you'll see that there is a redirection made towards `http://localhost:800`.

*To answer your last question :*
Accessing the url directly from the angular service may seem convenient for local development. But once you go and set your back-end on a different server than your front-end app, it can save you loads of time trying to figure out why there's a CORS error.

Comment: I can see url is redirecting to http://localhost:800/ on the angular console throws an error on the console. After changing url to http://localhost:8080/ in the proxy configuration file, I can see ```[HPM] /api/<end-point> -> http://localhost:8080/``` on the angular console. Request does not hit server and on the chrome dev tools, I can see error: ```Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/<end-point>: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/<endpoint>"```